# Seeing two instances of my app in eclipse servers pane?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I just upgraded to IBM Mobile First (worklight) 7.1.0.00.20150913-2345.

I've noticed that my app now shows twice in Eclipse servers pane. Other services shows twice too. Is this normal or something in my configuration is causing it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recent regression that was introduced in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1. It is harmless, but will be taken care of regardless...

If you so choose you can open a PMR (support ticket), but it is scheduled to be fixed regardless.

Comment: Thank you. It is harmless and it is planned to be solved so no problem! :)